# Remove some of series' labels in chart

Tags: echarts

I'm using echarts to display a stacked bar chart. There are 2 series of 360 data points. I'd like to show the series labels, there are 360 labels and they overlap and make it impossible to read the labels. Is there a way to automatically adjust how many labels are displayed? For example for 360 data points, it should only show 10 of those labels. The number of data points changes, so this has to be a dynamic solution based on the number of data points.

Currently, the labels look like this:
[image]

highcharts renders the same data like this:
[image]

My chart options:

```
      chartOptions: {
        tooltip: {
          trigger: 'axis',
          axisPointer: {
            type: 'shadow'
          }
        },
        grid: {
          left: '3%',
          right: '4%',
          bottom: '3%',
          containLabel: true
        },
        yAxis: {
          type: 'value'
        },
        xAxis: {
          type: 'category',
          data: Array.from(Array(360).keys())
        },
        series: [
          {
            name: 'Direct',
            type: 'bar',
            stack: 'total',
            label: {
              show: true
            },
            emphasis: {
              focus: 'series'
            },
            data: [
              180.80271365259728,
              181.78206168488214,
              182.76671451900847,
              183.75670088931975,
              184.75204968580374,
              185.752789954935,
              186.7589509005245,
              187.7705618845689,
              188.78765242811028,
              189.81025221209597,
              190.83839107824474,
              191.87209902991867,
              192.91140623299748,
              193.95634301675955,
              195.00693987476689,
              196.0632274657553,
              197.12523661452815,
              198.19299831285684,
              199.2665437203848,
              200.3459041655367,
              201.4311111464333,
              202.52219633180994,
              203.61919156194062,
              204.72212884956775,
              205.83104038083616,
              206.9459585162324,
              208.0669157915288,
              209.193944918733,
              210.32707878704264,
              211.46635046380584,
              212.61179319548478,
              213.76344040862705,
              214.9213257108404,
              216.08548289177406,
              217.25594592410448,
              218.4327489645268,
              219.6159263547513,
              220.80551262250606,
              222.00154248254466,
              223.20405083765854,
              224.41307277969577,
              225.62864359058585,
              226.85079874336816,
              228.07957390322804,
              229.3150049285373,
              230.5571278719001,
              231.80597898120618,
              233.0615947006877,
              234.32401167198304,
              235.59326673520627,
              236.86939693002205,
              238.15243949672617,
              239.44243187733332,
              240.739411716669,
              242.04341686346766,
              243.35448537147818,
              244.67265550057357,
              245.9979657178685,
              247.33045469884019,
              248.67016132845902,
              250.01712470232144,
              251.37138412779234,
              252.73297912515113,
              254.10194942874568,
              255.47833498815135,
              256.86217596933716,
              258.25351275583773,
              259.65238594993195,
              261.0588363738275,
              262.47290507085233,
              263.89463330665274,
              265.32406257039713,
              266.7612345759868,
              268.20619126327347,
              269.6589747992829,
              271.1196275794456,
              272.58819222883426,
              274.0647116034071,
              275.54922879125877,
              277.0417871138782,
              278.54243012741165,
              280.0512016239352,
              281.56814563273144,
              283.09330642157545,
              284.6267284980256,
              286.1684566107233,
              287.71853575069804,
              289.277011152681,
              290.8439282964247,
              292.41933290803036,
              294.00327096128217,
              295.59578867898915,
              297.19693253433377,
              298.8067492522281,
              300.42528581067756,
              302.0525894421522,
              303.68870763496375,
              305.33368813465313,
              306.98757894538244,
              308.65042833133657,
              310.3222848181314,
              312.00319719422953,
              313.693214512365,
              315.3923860909737,
              317.10076151563305,
              318.8183906405094,
              320.54532358981226,
              322.2816107592571,
              324.02730281753645,
              325.78245070779803,
              327.54710564913205,
              329.32131913806484,
              331.1051429500627,
              332.8986291410422,
              334.7018300488895,
              336.5147982949877,
              338.33758678575225,
              340.17024871417505,
              342.01283756137684,
              343.8654070981677,
              345.7280113866161,
              347.600704781627,
              349.4835419325274,
              351.376577784662,
              353.27986758099553,
              355.1934668637259,
              357.1174314759046,
              359.0518175630657,
              360.99668157486565,
              362.9520802667296,
              364.91807070150765,
              366.89471025114085,
              368.88205659833443,
              370.8801677382421,
              372.88910198015765,
              374.90891794921686,
              376.93967458810846,
              378.98143115879395,
              381.03424724423735,
              383.0981827501437,
              385.1732979067069,
              387.2596532703682,
              389.3573097255827,
              391.46632848659624,
              393.5867710992319,
              395.7186994426862,
              397.8621757313341,
              400.01726251654554,
              402.18402268851014,
              404.36251947807284,
              406.55281645857906,
              408.7549775477297,
              410.9690670094466,
              413.1951494557478,
              415.4332898486331,
              417.68355350198,
              419.9460060834491,
              422.2207136164011,
              424.50774248182336,
              426.80715942026654,
              429.1190315337931,
              431.44342628793447,
              433.78041151366085,
              436.1300554093599,
              438.4924265428273,
              440.8675938532675,
              443.2556266533061,
              445.65659463101144,
              448.07056785192935,
              450.49761676112723,
              452.93781218525,
              455.3912253345868,
              457.8579278051492,
              460.33799158076044,
              462.8314890351563,
              465.33849293409673,
              467.85907643748976,
              470.39331310152613,
              472.9412768808261,
              475.50304213059724,
              478.07868360880457,
              480.66827647835214,
              483.2718963092766,
              485.8896190809519,
              488.52152118430706,
              491.16767942405534,
              493.82817102093566,
              496.5030736139656,
              499.1924652627081,
              501.8964244495478,
              504.6150300819828,
              507.34836149492685,
              510.0964984530243,
              512.8595211529782,
              515.6375102258902,
              518.4305467396138,
              521.23871220112,
              524.0620885588761,
              526.9007582052368,
              529.7548039788485,
              532.6243091670672,
              535.5093575083888,
              538.4100331948925,
              541.3264208746982,
              544.2586056544361,
              547.206673101731,
              550.1707092476987,
              553.150800589457,
              556.14703409265,
              559.1594971939851,
              562.1882778037859,
              565.2334643085564,
              568.2951455735612,
              571.373410945418,
              574.4683502547057,
              577.5800538185853,
              580.708612443436,
              583.8541174275047,
              587.0166605635703,
              590.196334141623,
              593.3932309515568,
              596.6074442858777,
              599.8390679424263,
              603.0881962271143,
              606.3549239566778,
              609.6393464614432,
              612.9415595881093,
              616.2616597025449,
              619.5997436926003,
              622.9559089709353,
              626.3302534778612,
              629.7228756841996,
              633.1338745941557,
              636.5633497482073,
              640.0114012260101,
              643.4781296493177,
              646.9636361849182,
              650.4680225475864,
              653.9913910030526,
              657.5338443709858,
              661.0954860279953,
              664.6764199106469,
              668.2767505184962,
              671.8965829171381,
              675.5360227412725,
              679.1951761977878,
              682.8741500688591,
              686.5730517150655,
              690.2919890785221,
              694.0310706860307,
              697.7904056522468,
              701.5701036828632,
              705.370275077812,
              709.1910307344835,
              713.032482150962,
              716.8947414292796,
              720.7779212786883,
              724.6821350189477,
              728.6074965836337,
              732.5541205234617,
              736.5221220096305,
              740.5116168371826,
              744.5227214283841,
              748.5555528361211,
              752.6102287473168,
              756.6868674863647,
              760.7855880185825,
              764.9065099536832,
              769.0497535492657,
              773.2154397143241,
              777.4036900127767,
              781.6146266670127,
              785.848372561459,
              790.1050512461669,
              794.3847869404169,
              798.6877045363442,
              803.0139296025827,
              807.3635883879301,
              811.7368078250314,
              816.1337155340836,
              820.5544398265599,
              824.9991097089539,
              829.467854886544,
              833.9608057671794,
              838.4780934650851,
              843.0198498046875,
              847.586207324463,
              852.1772992808037,
              856.7932596519081,
              861.4342231416894,
              866.1003251837069,
              870.7917019451186,
              875.5084903306547,
              880.2508279866124,
              885.0188533048732,
              889.8127054269413,
              894.6325242480038,
              899.478450421014,
              904.3506253607944,
              909.2491912481654,
              914.1742910340929,
              919.126068443861,
              924.1046679812653,
              929.1102349328304,
              934.1429153720499,
              939.2028561636484,
              944.2902049678682,
              949.4051102447775,
              954.5477212586034,
              959.7181880820875,
              964.9166616008655,
              970.1432935178702,
              975.3982363577586,
              980.6816434713631,
              985.9936690401664,
              991.3344680808007,
              996.7041964495716,
              1002.1030108470068,
              1007.5310688224281,
              1012.9885287785496,
              1018.4755499761001,
              1023.9922925384706,
              1029.5389174563873,
              1035.1155865926094,
              1040.7224626866528,
              1046.3597093595388,
              1052.0274911185695,
              1057.7259733621286,
              1063.4553223845066,
              1069.2157053807562,
              1075.0072904515685,
              1080.8302466081811,
              1086.6847437773088,
              1092.5709528061025,
              1098.4890454671356,
              1104.439194463416,
              1110.4215734334261,
              1116.4363569561906,
              1122.48372055637,
              1128.5638407093836,
              1134.6768948465594,
              1140.8230613603116,
              1147.0025196093466,
              1153.2154499238973,
              1159.462033610985,
              1165.742452959711,
              1172.0568912465762,
              1178.4055327408284,
              1184.7885627098412,
              1191.2061674245197,
              1197.6585341647358,
              1204.1458512247948,
              1210.668307918929,
              1217.2260945868234,
              1223.8194025991686,
              1230.4484243632473,
              1237.1133533285483,
              1243.8143839924114,
              1250.5517119057035,
              1257.3255336785262
            ]
          },
          {
            name: 'Direct2',
            type: 'bar',
            stack: 'total',
            label: {
              show: true
            },
            emphasis: {
              focus: 'series'
            },
            data: [
              1083.3333333333333,
              1082.3539853010484,
              1081.369332466922,
              1080.3793460966108,
              1079.3839973001268,
              1078.3832570309955,
              1077.377096085406,
              1076.3654851013616,
              1075.3483945578203,
              1074.3257947738346,
              1073.2976559076858,
              1072.2639479560119,
              1071.224640752933,
              1070.179703969171,
              1069.1291071111636,
              1068.0728195201752,
              1067.0108103714024,
              1065.9430486730737,
              1064.8695032655457,
              1063.7901428203938,
              1062.7049358394972,
              1061.6138506541206,
              1060.51685542399,
              1059.4139181363628,
              1058.3050066050944,
              1057.1900884696981,
              1056.0691311944017,
              1054.9421020671975,
              1053.808968198888,
              1052.6696965221247,
              1051.5242537904458,
              1050.3726065773035,
              1049.2147212750901,
              1048.0505640941565,
              1046.880101061826,
              1045.7032980214037,
              1044.5201206311792,
              1043.3305343634245,
              1042.1345045033859,
              1040.931996148272,
              1039.7229742062348,
              1038.5074033953447,
              1037.2852482425624,
              1036.0564730827025,
              1034.8210420573932,
              1033.5789191140304,
              1032.3300680047244,
              1031.0744522852428,
              1029.8120353139475,
              1028.5427802507243,
              1027.2666500559085,
              1025.9836074892044,
              1024.6936151085972,
              1023.3966352692615,
              1022.0926301224629,
              1020.7815616144524,
              1019.463391485357,
              1018.138081268062,
              1016.8055922870903,
              1015.4658856574715,
              1014.1189222836091,
              1012.7646628581382,
              1011.4030678607794,
              1010.0340975571849,
              1008.6577119977792,
              1007.2738710165934,
              1005.8825342300928,
              1004.4836610359986,
              1003.077210612103,
              1001.6631419150782,
              1000.2414136792778,
              998.8119844155334,
              997.3748124099437,
              995.9298557226571,
              994.4770721866477,
              993.0164194064849,
              991.5478547570963,
              990.0713353825234,
              988.5868181946718,
              987.0942598720524,
              985.5936168585189,
              984.0848453619953,
              982.5679013531991,
              981.0427405643551,
              979.5093184879049,
              977.9675903752072,
              976.4175112352325,
              974.8590358332495,
              973.2921186895059,
              971.7167140779002,
              970.1327760246484,
              968.5402583069414,
              966.9391144515968,
              965.3292977337024,
              963.710761175253,
              962.0834575437783,
              960.4473393509668,
              958.8023588512774,
              957.1484680405481,
              955.485618654594,
              953.8137621677992,
              952.132849791701,
              950.4428324735655,
              948.7436608949569,
              947.0352854702975,
              945.3176563454211,
              943.5907233961183,
              941.8544362266734,
              940.1087441683941,
              938.3535962781325,
              936.5889413367985,
              934.8147278478657,
              933.0309040358678,
              931.2374178448883,
              929.434216937041,
              927.6212486909428,
              925.7984602001783,
              923.9657982717555,
              922.1232094245537,
              920.2706398877629,
              918.4080355993144,
              916.5353422043036,
              914.6525050534032,
              912.7594692012685,
              910.856179404935,
              908.9425801222046,
              907.0186155100259,
              905.0842294228648,
              903.1393654110649,
              901.183966719201,
              899.2179762844229,
              897.2413367347897,
              895.2539903875961,
              893.2558792476884,
              891.2469450057729,
              889.2271290367137,
              887.1963723978221,
              885.1546158271366,
              883.1017997416932,
              881.0378642357869,
              878.9627490792236,
              876.8763937155624,
              874.7787372603478,
              872.6697184993343,
              870.5492758866986,
              868.4173475432443,
              866.2738712545964,
              864.118784469385,
              861.9520242974204,
              859.7735275078577,
              857.5832305273515,
              855.3810694382008,
              853.166979976484,
              850.9408975301827,
              848.7027571372975,
              846.4524934839505,
              844.1900409024814,
              841.9153333695294,
              839.6283045041072,
              837.328887565664,
              835.0170154521375,
              832.6926206979961,
              830.3556354722697,
              828.0059915765706,
              825.6436204431033,
              823.268453132663,
              820.8804203326245,
              818.4794523549191,
              816.0654791340012,
              813.6384302248033,
              811.1982348006806,
              808.7448216513437,
              806.2781191807813,
              803.7980554051701,
              801.3045579507742,
              798.7975540518338,
              796.2769705484408,
              793.7427338844044,
              791.1947701051045,
              788.6330048553333,
              786.057363377126,
              783.4677705075784,
              780.8641506766539,
              778.2464279049786,
              775.6145258016235,
              772.9683675618752,
              770.3078759649949,
              767.6329733719649,
              764.9435817232225,
              762.2396225363827,
              759.5210169039477,
              756.7876854910037,
              754.0395485329062,
              751.2765258329523,
              748.4985367600403,
              745.7055002463168,
              742.8973347848105,
              740.0739584270544,
              737.2352887806937,
              734.381243007082,
              731.5117378188634,
              728.6266894775417,
              725.726013791038,
              722.8096261112323,
              719.8774413314944,
              716.9293738841995,
              713.9653377382318,
              710.9852463964735,
              707.9890128932806,
              704.9765497919454,
              701.9477691821446,
              698.9025826773741,
              695.8409014123694,
              692.7626360405126,
              689.6676967312249,
              686.5559931673453,
              683.4274345424946,
              680.2819295584259,
              677.1193864223602,
              673.9397128443076,
              670.7428160343737,
              667.5286027000528,
              664.2969790435043,
              661.0478507588163,
              657.7811230292527,
              654.4967005244873,
              651.1944873978213,
              647.8743872833857,
              644.5363032933302,
              641.1801380149952,
              637.8057935080693,
              634.4131713017309,
              631.0021723917748,
              627.5726972377232,
              624.1246457599204,
              620.6579173366129,
              617.1724108010123,
              613.6680244383441,
              610.1446559828779,
              606.6022026149448,
              603.0405609579352,
              599.4596270752836,
              595.8592964674343,
              592.2394640687925,
              588.600024244658,
              584.9408707881428,
              581.2618969170715,
              577.562995270865,
              573.8440579074085,
              570.1049762998998,
              566.3456413336837,
              562.5659433030673,
              558.7657719081185,
              554.945016251447,
              551.1035648349686,
              547.2413055566509,
              543.3581257072423,
              539.4539119669828,
              535.5285504022968,
              531.5819264624688,
              527.6139249763,
              523.6244301487479,
              519.6133255575464,
              515.5804941498094,
              511.52581823861374,
              507.44917949956584,
              503.350458967348,
              499.2295370322473,
              495.08629343666485,
              490.9206072716064,
              486.73235697315386,
              482.5214203189179,
              478.28767442447156,
              474.0309957397636,
              469.7512600455136,
              465.44834244958633,
              461.1221173833478,
              456.7724585980004,
              452.3992391608991,
              448.0023314518469,
              443.5816071593706,
              439.1369372769766,
              434.6681920993865,
              430.1752412187511,
              425.65795352084547,
              421.116197181243,
              416.54983966146756,
              411.9587477051268,
              407.34278733402243,
              402.7018238442412,
              398.03572180222363,
              393.34434504081196,
              388.62755665527584,
              383.8852189993181,
              379.1171936810573,
              374.3233415589892,
              369.5035227379267,
              364.6575965649165,
              359.7854216251361,
              354.88685573776513,
              349.96175595183763,
              345.0099785420696,
              340.03137900466527,
              335.02581205310014,
              329.9931316138807,
              324.9331908222821,
              319.8458420180623,
              314.7309367411531,
              309.5883257273272,
              304.417858903843,
              299.21938538506504,
              293.9927534680603,
              288.7378106281719,
              283.4544035145674,
              278.1423779457641,
              272.8015789051299,
              267.431850536359,
              262.03303613892376,
              256.60497816350244,
              251.14751820738093,
              245.66049700983046,
              240.14375444745997,
              234.59712952954328,
              229.02046039332117,
              223.41358429927777,
              217.77633762639175,
              212.10855586736102,
              206.41007362380196,
              200.6807246014239,
              194.92034160517437,
              189.12875653436208,
              183.3058003777494,
              177.45130320862177,
              171.56509417982807,
              165.64700151879492,
              159.69685252251452,
              153.7144735525044,
              147.69969002973994,
              141.65232642956062,
              135.57220627654692,
              129.4591521393711,
              123.31298562561892,
              117.13352737658397,
              110.92059706203327,
              104.67401337494562,
              98.39359402621949,
              92.07915573935429,
              85.73051424510209,
              79.34748427608929,
              72.92987956141087,
              66.47751282119475,
              59.99019576113574,
              53.4677390670015,
              46.90995239910717,
              40.316644386761936,
              33.68762262268319,
              27.022693657382206,
              20.321662993519112,
              13.584335080226992,
              6.810513307404335
            ]
          },
        ]
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, not sure if there is a built-in option

Modify char option, to use a  custom formatter:

```
            label: {
              show: true,
              formatter: myFormatter
            },
```

Implement a custom formatted, this assumes you want a total of 10 labels + a label for the very last data point. size is the size of the series (in my case 360).

```
function myFormatter(params, size) {
  if (params.dataIndex % Math.floor(size / 10) == 0 ||
      params.dataIndex == size - 1) { // make sure we have a label for the last datapoint
    return params.data
  }
  return ""
}
```